# How to rescue django project from unusable virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv, wagtail

I have a basic site using django/wagtail, that I had in a virtualenv. I was mainly working off of a nas device with an ARM processor. I transferred it recently to a virtual machine on my x86-64 laptop and wass unable to use it.

I learned why, learned the hard way that virtualenv is not a packaging mechanism. I just wondering what the 'best' way would be to rescue the django project and maybe somehow get a list of pip packages installed to the virtualenv (as pip freeze -r won't run due to the pip binary being for ARM).

Is there an easy way to do what I am asking, or would I be better off just trying to copy the django files and recreating the virtualenv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would create a `requirements.txt` file in your project and keep that in sync with the installed packages. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Every time you do `pip install some_package` you have to add that package to requirements.txt. Make sure you pin the version. Eg `pip install wagtail` the install of Wagtail runs. You'll see it picked the latest. Eg '2.1'. Add `wagtail==2.1` to your requirements.txt

Note that `pip freeze` will dump all installed packages. But normally you would only put the 'top level' packages (the packages you installed) in requirements.txt and NOT packages down the dependency tree. Since the dependencies might change when you upgrade the 'top level' package.

To anser your question:

Create a new virtualenv. Inspect the site-packages directory of your broken virtualenv. All installed (but broken) packages are in there. Including the used versions. Install all of them in the new env. Eg `pip install wagtail==2.1`

Comment: Adding to @allcaps answer, use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get `requirements.txt` directly. Also, I'd recommend that you use `pipenv` instead of just `pip`.

Comment: Yes, dumping the output of any command to a file works with `>`. But what I wrote, `pip freeze` dumps too much. That is okay if you really want to freeze the project and never upgrade. But you're likely want to upgrade in the future. Then you only want to pin the 'top level' packages (Wagtail, Django, ...) and NOT their dependencies. As the dependencies are defined in the setup.py. Eg: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/setup.py#L23